# What is the simplist possible PDF file that makes a black box?

Tags: pdf-generation, cairo

I would like to create a simple PDF file that makes a black box. I want the absolute simplest PDF file. I'm doing this for education and analysis purposes.

I've tried creating super-simple PS and converting the PS into PDF. I've also tried creating the PDF with Cairo. That gives me a 928-byte file with some extraneous information that needs to be removed, and also with an object that needs to be decoded with `/FlateDecode`

- Is there any way to get Cairo not to compress in PDF output?
- Is there any way to get Cairo to suppress the `/Creator` and `/Producer` and other information?

Failing that, what is the simplest PDF that can be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) contains examples of various PDF files in Appendix H.

The very first example in this appendix shows minimal PDF file (read annotation to it).

The third example (Simple Graphics example) shows how to draw a rectangle with a 1−unit red border, filled with light blue. It's not exactly a black box and there other shapes in the example, but might give enough information for a start.